# How dangerous is it to allow a "sandboxed" program to write anywhere in virtual memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, security, process, memory, verification

This is a question about the interaction between a process and the linux kernel. This is in the context of a formal proof, so the setting may seem a bit weird. Suppose I have a program, loaded from an ELF file in the usual way, that cannot write to its own code segment nor its data segment in let's say "unapproved" ways, and it also cannot issue unapproved system calls, but it can write to any other position in memory (which is to say, it is allowed to issue a write to any location). Is this safe? It is okay if the program accesses an unmapped page, because this will cause a segmentation fault, which will cause the program to visibly exit with an error. (The concern is whether the program can *not* exit and instead do unapproved things.)

Besides a segfault, what kinds of effects are possible if you write to random places in memory? For instance, is there any MMIO or secret alternative syscall / kernel communication mechanism sitting in a process-visible page?

The statement I would like to be true is the following: If memory addresses [x-y] (the code & data of the program) contain value V and a write is issued to a location outside [x-y], then either the process exits with an error code, or the memory at [x-y] still contains V (and all other process invariants still hold: the process is still in user mode, the kernel has not created any MMIO mappings, etc.).

- If the page mapping contains a mirror outside [x-y], it may be possible for a write outside [x-y] to succeed and alter data in [x-y]. But I don't think the kernel normally produces these kinds of pages unless you ask it to.
- There is a mapped vDSO page somewhere in virtual memory, but writing to it should be fine since I don't need these functions.

The main reason I want to be able to write to memory is to simplify stack handling. Most compilers produce no stack bounds checking and linux imperfectly protects against stack overflow using a guard page. I believe it is possible to circumvent the guard by allocating a very large array on the stack and accessing a well chosen index into it. If this accesses the data page of the application the program will surely break, so this at least needs protection, but I don't know what else needs protection as well. How near can heap allocations (`mmap`ped pages and `sbrk`) get to the stack?

It seems like it should be possible to get a standards conformant C program to violate the abstract semantics using a "stack smashing" technique like this (using either a large constant size array or `alloca` to allocate huge amounts of memory without telling the kernel, then using `malloc` to acquire memory inside the large array because the kernel doesn't know it's already allocated, and then writes to the array can change the contents of the `malloc`'d region).

Comment: What is your threat model? Your program runs in its own virtual address space, and can indeed do nasty things like overflow the stack. But it can only hurt itself, not overwrite other processes' memory or kernel memory. If it does this inadvertently, there is a bug in your program, it does this on purpose, "well, don't do that then". The Unix protection model is intended to protect processes from interference from other processes and users, not to prevent processes from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: @ilkkachu [see the stackguard CVEs](https://access.redhat.com/security/vulnerabilities/stackguard)

Comment: @StephenKitt, yepp

Comment: @JohanMyréen I want to prevent the program from "failing successfully", that is, it is only allowed to fail in a noisy way like a SIGBUS exception, rather than causing subtle memory corruption that will cause some incorrect result to be computed without visible evidence of failure. The point here is to define what constitutes a "bug". The fact that conventional C programs *rely* on stack protection indicates that it is not as simple as merely "never access read-protected memory", so I am trying to determine what weaker guarantee suffices.

Comment: (Plus, even saying "only attempt to access memory you have access to" is also insufficient since who knows what random writable pages might exist out there somewhere in virtual memory space. I don't know if I can be sure that none of those regions have funny side-effectful behavior.)

Comment: You are right in that jumping over the stack guard page can lead to subtle failures or even vulnerabilities if an outsider is able to control the allocation. However, the fix must be implemented in user space, since the kernel can't really intervene as long as there is no fault. The "allocation" is basically a modification of the stack pointer value, which can result in the new value pointing to some other writable memory area (e.g. the heap). A write through this pointer is also a valid CPU instruction: no trap, and execution continues without the kernel being aware of the error.

Comment: Yes, it’s an aliasing problem, which seems out of scope given a strict reading of the question...

Comment: I'm not saying the kernel should intervene and fix anything. What I'm really after is a formal definition of the kernel interface for user programs, but as far as I'm aware no such thing exists so I have to write one myself. So it's perfectly fine to have restrictions that cannot be checked, like "never set the stack pointer to your heap segment"; it's just a rule that user programs have to follow, kind of like C undefined behavior. ...

Comment: ... But what needs to be prevented is the user program accidentally stumbling on a patch of "weird" memory which is not simply a storage location and instead has a special property like MMIO, mirroring, or random kernel escalation, because the memory model doesn't account for this. My presumption is that correct C programs exist, but the stack allocation technique is very common (it's in essentially every C program ever) and so there should be some explanation why it is not wrong in the common case.

Comment: What I meant with kernel intervention is that the program would fail in a "noisy way", i.e. an exception. As to whether a program can stumble upon "weird" memory: the short answer is no, it can't. Normal, non-root processes are provided with their own "sandboxes". The kernel sets up a mapping for the process, and the process can access memory within the limits of the mapping with whatever mechanism it chooses. The kernel can't trust that the process behaves correctly, it must enforce it. Otherwise a malicious program could very easily exploit this hole (no accident needed).